# SQLite and UWP, UseWinsqlite3

Tags: sqlite, win-universal-app

Does anybody knows why i get error using this namespace "UseWinsqlite3"?

I have already installed Entity Framework Commands,Entity Framework SQL and SQLite for Universal Windows Platform  packages .

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseWinsqlite3("Filename=Sensors.database");
    }
```

Currently working on Visual Studio 2015 ( UWP )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no "UseWinsqlite3" in EF Core.

Please refer to the links below:

http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5325